# Embedding doesn't work with django-embed-video on HTTPS site

Tags: html, django, https, youtube

I am using `django-embed-video` to embed videos from YouTube and Vimeo on my site. It works quite fine. But now I switched to `https` and videos suddenly stopped to work. Have you any idea why?

Output from `pip freeze`

```
Django==1.5
distribute==0.6.34
django-embed-video==0.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

in console log I have had:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://localhost:8000/articles/my-test/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/g9fHqTOYpm4?wmode=opaque': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Which version of django-embed-video do you use?

Comment: I dont know. How can I find it out?

Comment: ``pip freeze`` if you are using pip, or ``import embed_video; print embed_video.__version__`` from python console.

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console? Maybe `embed-video` is trying to include javascript files from `http://` urls, which are blocked in newer browsers

Comment: Yeah, I guess it might be problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade `django-embed-video`.

Support for HTTPS sites [has been added in version 0.7](http://django-embed-video.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7/development/changelog.html#release-0-7-dec-21-2013). You can read more about [this problem](https://github.com/yetty/django-embed-video/issues/11) in issue in Github repository.